# ACER g247hyl and GTX 950 MSI 2G GAMING - VGA or HDMI?

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi, vga

I have purchased ACER g247hyl 24 inch monitor and currently using gtx 950 MSI Gaming 2G for gaming purpose. Now for example, if I play fifa 15 in 720p, 1080p rsolution, games graphics seems crappy especially player graphics when camera moves.

I am currently using VGA cable to connect. Do I have to use HDMI to overcome above issue? or May be it is something else causing crappy graphics?

Comment: HDMI will provide better quality than VGA, but it is still unclear what do you mean by saying "crappy graphics". There could be many other reasons for it.

Comment: I am not sure what is causing that, tried to change the resolution and now I have HDMI cable but still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

VGA is an analogue standard which tends (in my experience) to look less sharp than a digital connection such as HMDI, DVI or displayport. So from a quality point of view, you may be better switching to HDMI.

I don't believe that VGA vs HMDI will affect the framerate. Your performance issues are more likely to be affected by your screen resolution settings. Do you get better performance when you lower the screen resolution?

Comment: I am not sure what is causing that, tried to change the resolution and now I have HDMI cable but still the same issue. Also my rig is way high than minimum or maximum requirement.